# Joomla 3 File Upload Front-End - file not uploading

Tags: joomla3.0

I have the following form in a custom J3 front-end component:

```
<form method="post" id="upload-photo-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upload-photo-file" accept="image/*"/>
```

I am able to select a file in the form, a .jpg. I then try to retrieve the file data in the component:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication ();
$file = $app->input->files->get('upload-photo-file');
```

The retrieved $file is empty. I can't figure out why. Other (hidden) input in the form is being passed through post correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Stupid development process mistake. I was testing with the wrong code.